# Is there a list of default magento attributes?

Tags: product, csv, pricing

I am scrubbing a product spreadsheet csv.  I would like to know if these are custom, configured, or default. By configured I mean if something like customer groups were created and price tiers were set.

I have these attributes.

```
_tier_price_website
_tier_price_customer_group  
_tier_price_qty 
_tier_price_price   
_group_price_website    
_group_price_customer_group 
_group_price_price
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try installing fresh xampp magento and see its attributes list. Thats what I do when I want to see something default. Sometimes it takes longer to google such things, then taking matter up your own hands, in case here is the list of default attributes:

- color
- cost
- country_of_manufacture
- custom_design
- custom_design_from
- custom_design_to
- custom_layout_update
- description
- gallery
- gift_message_available
- group_price
- image
- is_recurring
- manufacturer
- media_gallery
- meta_description
- meta_keyword
- meta_title
- msrp
- msrp_display_actual_price_type
- msrp_enabled
- name
- news_from_date
- news_to_date
- options_container
- page_layout
- price
- price_view
- recurring_profile
- short_description
- sku
- small_image
- special_from_date
- special_price
- special_to_date
- status
- tax_class_id
- thumbnail
- tier_price
- url_key
- visibility
- weight